# Create azure hdinsight by node.js command line interface report "Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, azure, hadoop, command-line-interface, azure-hdinsight

I'v created a hdinsight cluster config and then create cluster by command 'azure hdinsight cluster create --config myhdinsightconf', but reported

> info:    Executing command hdinsight cluster create
>   /error:   Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined
>   info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
>   error:   hdinsight cluster create command failed

azure.err files

```
    Wed Mar 05 2014 10:47:34 GMT+0800 (CST):
    { [TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined]
        stack: [Getter/Setter],
       __frame: 
       { name: 'getCluster__2',
            line: 176,
            file: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js',
            prev: 
                { name: 'createClusterCommand__1',
                line: 253,
                file: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js',
                prev: undefined,
                active: false,
                offset: 41,
                col: 19 },
            active: true,
            offset: 1,
            col: 17 },
        rawStack: [Getter] }
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined
        at ___ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js:183:40)
        at ___ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:85:13)
        at ___ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js:196:16)
        at ___ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:85:13)
        at finalCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/hdinsight/hdinsightservice.js:403:7)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:693:11
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/hdinsight/hdinsightservice.js:406:5
        at Request.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:219:13)
        at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/node_modules/request/request.js:129:22)
        at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at getCluster__2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js:177:17)
        at createClusterCommand__1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/hdinsight._js:294:19)
```

node -v
v0.10.26

Same error is reported when create without config file. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error report is not precise totally. I tried on management portal, hdinsight is not available for the zone of my config, and there are at least 10 character password length limit. The error was gone when I fixed these problems.